# How to monitor Apache Spark with Prometheus?

Tags: apache-spark, prometheus

I have read that Spark does not have Prometheus as one of the pre-packaged sinks. So I found this [post](https://banzaicloud.github.io/blog/spark-monitoring/) on how to monitor Apache Spark with prometheus.

But I found it difficult to understand and to success because I am beginner and this is a first time to work with Apache Spark.

First thing that I do not get is what I need to do?

- I need to change the metrics.properties
- Should I add some code in the app or?

I do not get what are the steps to make it...

The thing that I am making is: changing  the properties like in the link, write this command:

> ```
> --conf spark.metrics.conf=<path_to_the_file>/metrics.properties
> ```

And what else I need to do to see metrics from Apache spark?

Also I found this links:
[Monitoring Apache Spark with Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488956/monitoring-apache-spark-with-prometheus)

https://argus-sec.com/monitoring-spark-prometheus/

But I could not make it with it too...

I have read that there is a way to get metrics from Graphite and then to export them to Prometheus but I could not found some useful doc.

Comment: this blog has a good and detail explanation. https://argus-sec.com/monitoring-spark-prometheus/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few ways to monitoring Apache Spark with Prometheus.

One of the way is by `JmxSink + jmx-exporter`

### Preparations

- Uncomment *.sink.jmx.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.JmxSink in spark/conf/metrics.properties
- Download jmx-exporter by following link on [prometheus/jmx_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter)
- Download [Example prometheus config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/master/example_configs/spark.yml)

### Use it in spark-shell or spark-submit

In the following command, the `jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar` file and the `spark.yml` are downloaded in previous steps. It might need be changed accordingly.

```
bin/spark-shell --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=8080:spark.yml"
```

### Access it

After running, we can access with [localhost:8080/metrics](http://localhost:8080/metrics)

### Next

It can then configure prometheus to scrape the metrics from jmx-exporter.

> NOTE: We have to handle to discovery part properly if it's running in a cluster environment.

Comment: ,what needs to  be done for spark cluster, can you provide steps for the same.

Comment: in order to scrap the metrics from jmx-exporter you have to add on the file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` the lines `- job_name: "spark_streaming_app"  scrape_interval: "5s"  static_configs:  - targets: ['localhost:8082']`

Comment: How do you scrape a custom metric from your Spark app?

Comment: I'm getting `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing` while running it with mentioned command

Answer (score 8):

### PrometheusServlet

Things have since changed and the latest Spark 3.2 comes with Prometheus support built-in using [PrometheusServlet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics):

> The metrics system is configured via a configuration file that Spark expects to be present at `$SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties`.

> `PrometheusServlet`: (Experimental) Adds a servlet within the existing Spark UI to serve metrics data in Prometheus format.

### spark.ui.prometheus.enabled

There is also [spark.ui.prometheus.enabled](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#executor-metrics) configuration property:

> Executor metric values and their measured memory peak values per executor are exposed via the REST API in JSON format and in Prometheus format.

> The Prometheus endpoint is conditional to a configuration parameter: `spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true` (the default is `false`).

### Demo

#### spark.ui.prometheus.enabled

Start a Spark application with `spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true`, e.g.

```
spark-shell \
  --master spark://localhost:7077 \
  --conf spark.ui.prometheus.enabled=true
```

Open http://localhost:4040/metrics/executors/prometheus and you should see the following page:

```
spark_info{version="3.2.0", revision="5d45a415f3a29898d92380380cfd82bfc7f579ea"} 1.0
metrics_executor_rddBlocks{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_memoryUsed_bytes{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_diskUsed_bytes{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_totalCores{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_maxTasks{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_activeTasks{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_failedTasks_total{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
metrics_executor_completedTasks_total{application_id="app-20211107174758-0001", application_name="Spark shell", executor_id="driver"} 0
```

#### PrometheusServlet

Use (uncomment) the following `conf/metrics.properties`:

```
*.sink.prometheusServlet.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.PrometheusServlet
*.sink.prometheusServlet.path=/metrics/prometheus
```

Start a Spark application (e.g. `spark-shell`) and go to http://localhost:4040/metrics/prometheus. You should see the following page:

```
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_disk_diskSpaceUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_disk_diskSpaceUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOffHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOffHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOnHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_maxOnHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_memUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_memUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_offHeapMemUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_offHeapMemUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_onHeapMemUsed_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_onHeapMemUsed_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingOffHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingOffHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingOnHeapMem_MB_Number{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_BlockManager_memory_remainingOnHeapMem_MB_Value{type="gauges"} 868
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_job_activeJobs_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_job_activeJobs_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_job_allJobs_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_job_allJobs_Value{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_stage_failedStages_Number{type="gauges"} 0
metrics_app_20211107173310_0000_driver_DAGScheduler_stage_failedStages_Value{type="gauges"} 0
```

Comment: This requires a service monitor deployed in prometheus right ?

Comment: I am also interested in this approach because this idea exposes the metrics in the driver but it does not tell Prometheus where to scrape the metrics.

Answer (score 4):

I have followed the GitHub readme and it worked for me (the original blog assumes that you use the Banzai Cloud fork as they were expected the PR to accepted upstream). They externalized the sink to a standalone project (https://github.com/banzaicloud/spark-metrics) and I used that to make it work with Spark 2.3.

Actually you can scrape (Prometheus) through JMX, and in that case you don't need the sink - the Banzai Cloud folks did a post about how they use JMX for Kafka, but actually you can do this for any JVM.

So basically you have two options:

- use the sink
- or go through JMX,

they open sourced both options.

Comment: Can you write what have you done step by step? Btw thank you for the good explanation!

Comment: Can you make that @Mark ?